# Why does Windows prompt to format USB drive when I replace the MBR?

Tags: assembly, filesystems, nasm, bootloader, dd

I am writing a bootloader in 8086 assembly under Windows using *NASM*. After building it I write it to USB media of 16GB with FAT32 file system using the *DD* utility. The command I use to update the MBR is:

```
dd if=source.bin od=drive: bs=512 count=1
```

After using *DD* to update the MBR, Windows asks me to format it. Why does Windows do this? Is it because I corrupted the file system? How can I rectify this so that writing my MBR doesn't cause Windows to think I may need to reformat the USB drive?

My bootloader/bootsector includes a BIOS Parameter block for a FAT32 file system. Despite this my problem persists.

Comment: is there a partition table on the USB, if not, it would be unrecognised. Note, BIOS parameter block <> partition table.

Comment: I don't know. But I just performed a format(Not a quick one) before writing file to the boot sector.

Comment: Windows partitions and formats a floppy differently than a USB device.On a floppy there is no partition data and the information in the BPB is sufficient to define the file system on the media. When Windows partitions and formats a USB device it actually places an MBR on the disk with a BPB and it contains a [Partition table](http://wiki.osdev.org/Partition_Table) in the last 64 bytes of the MBR, It will have one partition and it will be marked active.Likely you have no partition table in your bootloader.When you write yours onto the disk, Windows see no partition tables and requests to format

Comment: One hackish way to resolve this is to download [chrysocome's 0.6beta3 _DD_](http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.6beta3.zip). This tool (you may already have it) can be used to read sectors from a disk. Reformat your USB device (if it isn't already) use a command like this to read the bootloader/MBR that Windows wrote: `dd id=e: of=winboot.mbr count=1` . Replace `e:` with the drive letter of your USB. This command would write the MBR of the USB device into the file `winboot.mbr`.

Comment: You could then use a hex editor or hexdump type utility to view the file and look at the 64 bytes just before boot signature (0xaa55). Then you add the values of those 64 bytes to your bootloader's MBR placing them before the disk signature (0xaa55). This may be enough to keep Windows happy.

Comment: Please note: I haven't even tried it, but I think there is a reasonable chance that it may work.

Comment: In order to make you question more useful it may also help if you post your bootloader code.

Comment: How to write a file to 3rd sector of a disk using dd utility

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for Windows to ask to reformat a USB stick:

1. The MBR is corrupt;
2. The MBR doesn't identify any partitions that Windows recognises.

(1) is only detected if bytes 0x1FE and 0x1FF of the MBR aren't 0x55 and 0xAA respectively.

(2) is more difficult: the partition table (4 16-byte entries at 0x1BE, 0x1CE, 0x1DE, 0x1EE) doesn't list a known partition type at offset 0x03 in any (or just the first!) entry.